# C++ STL Map gives TLE when looping with auto?

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, stl, auto

I was working on [this](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/799/B) problem on CodeForces. My solution was giving TLE and I could not figure out why. Eventually I narrowed it to the faulty line and it was essentially the following

```
// map<int, set<long long>> res;
for(auto z : res) if(res[z.first].count(x)) res[z.first].erase(x);
```

This gives TLE on Test case 6. Now my res map has three keys at max (1,2,3). If I change the loop to-

```
for(int j = 1; j<=3; j++) if(res[j].count(x)) res[j].erase(x);
```

then the solution works and runs for all test cases. I want to understand why does the first loop not work and how to know when can I use that loop and when not?

[Link](https://codeforces.com/problemset/submission/799/187407911) to TLE submission. [Link](https://codeforces.com/problemset/submission/799/187408008) to correct submission. Only difference is in line 81-82.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(auto z : res)
```

It copies the inner maps to `z` pairs each loop iteration. Try

```
for(auto& z : res)
```

Comment: This worked! I wasn't aware it copied the whole map to z at each iteration. Thanks!